# Number of Adults and Number of Children as quantity in configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, bundled-product, grouped-products

I have tried various combination of configurable, bundled, grouped products and custom options but none of combinations could give me below output in Magento:

[image]

The final price should be:
(Rate for adult **for the option selected** * Adult Quantity) + (Rate for child **for the option selected** * Child Quantity)

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

This would be something like a configurable product where the simple associated products are actually grouped products. This combination is not possible with Magento.

I would use a bundle product instead:

- first, create the simple products:

  - "collosseum package experience adult"
  - "collosseum package experience child"
  - "collosseum package experience early bird adult"
  - "collosseum package experience early bird child"
- create a bundle with the following options:

  - adults (not required, customizable qty):

    - collosseum package experience
    - collosseum package experience early bird
  - children (not required, customizable qty):

    - collosseum package experience
    - collosseum package experience early bird

On the frontend you will have two dropdowns with a qty input each, one for adults and one for children.

If it is important for you that the frontend looks like in your screenshot, you could hide the default inputs, create your own in a custom template and use JavaScript to map the selection to the default inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm not comfortable with relying only on Javascript as I have faced issues in past. I am considering creating a custom product type but not sure if that's going too far.

Comment: That's about 100 times the effort and Magento does not work without Javascript anyways, so I'd reconsider that

Comment: Agree. I'm not saying that I will not use javascript. Just saying that a php check would make sure that nothing is missed.

Comment: So you think that the bundle product could be misconfigured? This should not be possible if you use the "select" type for the bundle options.

Comment: No, but bundle product will not be enough here. The custom javascript will play a key role here.

Comment: Could you update your question to explain why?

Comment: The reason is simple. The calculation of total price will be done using javascript. Sometimes, the user selects option before jQuery loads completely.

Comment: The calculation of the total price is nothing, your custom JavaScript has to do. When you update the hidden inputs, Magento will calculate the total price with its own Javascript in bundle.js (no jQuery)